# Erro em programa C (cálculo de determinantes)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void zerar(int n,int m[][n]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void printm(int n, int matriz[][n]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("\t%d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int det(int n, int matriz[][n]) {
    int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[10][10];
    zerar(n, aux);
    if (n < 1) {}
    else if (n == 1) {
        return matriz[0][0];
    }
    else if (n == 2) {
        soma = (matriz[0][0] * matriz[1][1]) - (matriz[0][1] * matriz[1][0]);
        return soma;
    }
    else {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=1, x=0; j<n; j++) {
                for (k=0, y=0; k<n; k++) {
                    if (k == i) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("\n\n");
                        printm(n-1, aux);
                        aux[x][y] = matriz[j][k];
                        printf("\nx=%d, y=%d, j=%d, k=%d, i=%d\n", x, y, j, k, i);
                        y++;
                    }
                }
                x++;
            }
            soma += matriz[0][i]*pow(-1, i+2)*det(n-1, aux);
        }
        return soma;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int m[3][3] = {{4, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 5}, {2, 1, 2}};
    det(3, m);
    printf("%d", det(3, m));
    printf("\n\n");
    printm(3, m);
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

http://pastebin.com/6iGeaxHD#

No "else" da linha 41 coloquei uma função pra printar a matriz auxiliar e um printf para exibir os valores dos contadores à cada passo, fazendo isso encontrei o problema: não estão sendo gravados valores na 2ª linha da matriz auxiliar em nenhum dos casos, mantendo o valor `0` (valor com o qual foram inicializados esses elementos).
Como posso corrigir??

Exemplo: no primeiro laço for da função `det`, quando roda com o valor `i=0`,
é printada a seguinte matriz auxiliar após toda a exibição:

```
4 5
0 0
```

quando deveria ser:

```
4 5
1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

Seu problema é na forma como você está criando o array `aux`:

```
int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[10][10];
```

Você está criando ele com tamanho 10x10, o que significa que internamente uma sequência de 100 elementos é criada. Então, quando você atribui:

```
aux[1][0] = 1;
```

É o 11º elemento que está sendo atribuído. Seu array então termina assim:

```
4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
```

Quando você tenta passar esse array pra função `det` (ou mesmo `printm`), você estabelece que o tamanho da matriz é `n` - no caso `2`:

```
int det(int n, int matriz[][n]) {
```

Então ele pega apenas os 4 primeiros elementos do array!

```
4 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...
^^^^^^^
```

Pra solucionar isso, crie sua variável `aux` com o tamanho correto que pretende usar:

```
int i, j, k, x, y, soma=0, aux[n-1][n-1];
```

[Exemplo funcionando no ideone](https://ideone.com/EUo35A).